# Can't figure out how to get response from symfomy2 my controller in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I've implemented a signin form that submits its values through ajax successfuly. When values match one of the database ones everything is setup and naturally when values don't match the user is not connected.

The thing is, i am always getting a 200 status as a response from my controller and i can't tell if the process went right or wrong.

I know php always returns 200 status when everything technically went right but how can i set and get the correct values from my controller i can read in my javascript code and be able to tell if things went ok or not?

Here is some parts of my code :

//Controller

```
[...]
if ($logForm -> isValid()) {
            //Check user infos in database
            [...]

            if ( ! $user) {
                //We set an error
                $resp = array('responseCode' => 400, "message" => "Bad authentification");
            } else {

                $resp = array('responseCode' => 200, "message" => "Good authentification");
            }

            $resp = json_encode($resp);
            return new Response($resp, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
        }
[...]
```

//jQuery

```
$('#signInForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    //console.log(form);

    if(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('ajax_sign_in'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            statusCode: {
                200: function(v) {
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                400: function(e) {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error submitting form");
    }
})
```

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you just use a variable like status whitch return true or false ? It's easier to use than a request statuscode

Comment: Using error codes in this way, how would you differentiate a network or other error from a failed login attempt? As stated by prior commenter, I'd use an explicit variable.

Comment: I do not have symfony here to verify this, but as you are returning response value.  Can you not check `if (v["message"] == "Good authentification")` in your status 200 javascript?

Comment: I've tried to console.log(v['message']) as you suggested but it returns "undefined"

Comment: Use json_encode($array) in php to stringify your php array

Comment: I am already using it $resp = json_encode($resp);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just do this?

```
return new Response($resp, $resp['responseCode'], array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the time you spent trying to help me! I finaly got it working. This code is working. The problem came from the routing. Since i am handling both when javascript is activated and when it's not i should have been using two distincts routes when i was using only one.